# What should an action filter do when an action argument is invalid?

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-web-api

I can use an action filter to validate it's parameters, right? So I'm writing this filter and I'm wondering what is the correct way to handle an invalid value? Should the action filter throw an exception or assign some value to `context.Result`? When it needs to assign a value, what value would it be and do I then call `next` anyway or do I skip it?

```cs
internal class ValidateWorkflowState : IAsyncActionFilter
{
    private static readonly IEnumerable<string> ValidStates = new[] { "enabled", "disabled", "any" };

    public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        if (context.ActionArguments.TryGetValue("state", out var state) && !ValidStates.Contains(state))
        {
            // What do I do here? 
        }

        await next();
    }
}
```

The action has this signature:

```cs
[HttpGet("store/{state=enabled}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetWorkflowStore(string state)
{
    // ...
}
```